# Mariadb on Termux Android not accessible

Tags: android, flutter, mariadb, termux

I installed Mariadb server / Termux on an Android phone (Huawei) and an Android tablet.

In Termux, Mariadb was launched using:

```
mysqld_safe -u root &
```

On the Huawei phone, Mariadb server is accessible only when Termux is currently running in the foreground. After I closed Termux, without terminating, Mariadb is no longer accessible.

On the Android tablet, Mariadb server is accessible even after Termux is closed (without terminating).

I am using flutter to access Mariadb using the driver 'mysql1'.

Is this behaviour specific to a particular version of Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Huawei's android killing background apps. try to ignore termux from battry optimization [article about it](https://support.doubletwist.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001504071-How-to-turn-off-battery-optimization-on-Huawei-devices)

use termux service for run mysql [termux services docs](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-services)